# Check equality between N > 2 arrays with maximum performance?

Tags: javascript, arrays, equality

I'd like to check if `n` arrays all contain the same integers in JavaScript? What is the most efficient way?

Comment: I'd imagine sorting would help improve performance when checking values between every array. You could check at each index for instance. 
Open to hearing both approaches - sorting and not sorting.

Comment: For clarification, what would be the expected output if array1 doesn't equal array2 but  array2 equal array3 ?

Comment: If any of the n arrays are not equal return false

Comment: Use Underscore.js. Those guys are performance freaks.... See this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110510/underscore-js-determine-if-all-values-in-an-array-of-arrays-match

Comment: thanks - this is perfect.

Comment: in theory, most optimal is to get the count of all items using hashMap. In practice it can depend on number of items, frequency, and others

Comment: `[1, 3, 5]` and `[1, 3, 5, 1, 5]` contain the same integers. Would they be considered "equal"?

Comment: They would not be equal. As a first step I'm going to check if the arrays are the same length.

Comment: They can be the same length and have the same integers. For example: `[1, 1, 2]` and `[1, 2, 2]` have the same integers and length.

Comment: `String(arr1)==String(arr2)` should be really fast if you have all ints

Comment: @dandavis not exactly: `String(['1','2','3']) === String([1,2,3])` but you are right if they are integers it would not be an issue. JSON.stringify() would be safer.

Comment: @dandavis this fails if the arrays are not sorted.

Comment: That's a very legit question - why would ppl downvote that? Stack should require justification on downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have only numbers in the arrays - use some variation of the basic CRC algorithm - the complexity is O(n) per array so it would be the fastest possible https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check

Similar idea, calculate sum(array) and product(array), you can calculate both values with O(n). For example:

```
   1, 5, 6, 7 ,8      sum=27, prod=1680
   7, 8, 1, 5, 6      sum=27, prod=1680
```

but

```
   3, 8, 5, 5, 6      sum=27, prod=3600
```

**NOTE** special case is 0! Since that will nullify the product this all values should be used +1.

**NOTE2**
Keep in mind that the idea behind CRC algorithms is to use one byte or dword variable for the total and the variable will eventually overflow.

For example in the case of byte: 250 + 10 = 5, as the byte overflows at 255. However it is okay as both arrays would overflow and the chance for false report is very small. I believe that if we can try hard we can prove it mathematically that is okay.

However, If you lazy to do the math and absolute certainty is required you can use this method quick filtering of all negative candidates and then sort+compare only the positive candidates. Still will be way faster than using only sort+compare.

**NOTE3:** 
Just realized you're using JS and JS is a bit messy with big numbers and doesn't really overflow with arithmetical operations.

However it does overflow with logical operators and the CRC algorithm does use xor so you are good. This is the CRC algo: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check

And this is some open source implemention: https://github.com/emn178/js-crc/blob/master/src/crc.js
On prima vista seems to follow the algorithm, however I am not sure how quality it is, so do your due diligence!

Comment: Could you provide an example - preferably in javascript? I googled CRC but it didn't turn up much...

Comment: try "crc algorithm" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check, I updated my answer with the exact idea I had in mind hopefully it would work for you

Comment: If the arrays contain -1 adding 1 won't fix your 0 problem for product.

Comment: what's with the neg vots - this is a conceptual suggestion that would work. 
If you have a better idea post it or make a constructive comment

Comment: This is great. The solution includes a unique insight into the problem that is simple, and is very performant. I suppose you could handle 0's by adding some control flow that added 1 for every 0 as long as you only check the sum. Do you have to check both product and sum?

Comment: yes you should check both sum and prod. look at the examples. The 3rd example gives you the same sum like the other two sets but it is not a match. Only match by prod and sum together will give you true match..

Comment: @zero_cool this is very good for smaller arrays, but doesn't seem like it would work in rare cases where the product is bigger than [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Answer (score 1):

This solution avoids using `sort`, making the algorithm O(n²), where n is the number of and lengths of the arrays.  It has the added benefit of not mutating the arrays and also let's you pass arrays containing any types, not just numbers.  It operates by computing a frequency bag for each array item, then assessing whether they all hold the same data.  The `toBag` and `bagsEqual` functions are both O(n).  This makes the main algorithm `arraysSame` O(n²).  Using `sort` instead of frequency bags would make the solution O(n²log(n)), which isn't nearly as favorable.

```
function arraysSame(...arrays) {
  if(arrays.length < 2) return true;

  let bag1 = toBag(arrays[0]);
  for(let i = 1; i < arrays.length; i++) {
    const bag2 = toBag(arrays[i]);
    if(!bagsEqual(bag1, bag2)) return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function bagsEqual(bag1, bag2) {
  if(bag1.size != bag2.size) return false;

  for(const [key, value] of bag1) {
    if(!bag2.has(key)) return false;
    if(value != bag2.get(key)) return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function toBag(array) {
  const bag = new Map();

  for(const val of array) {
    const count = bag.get(val) || 0;
    bag.set(val, count + 1);
  }

  return bag;
}
```